# Opening a modal using a partial view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to open a modal whenever a button is pressed. The button and modal are in an cshtml file that is ran as a partial view.

LoginModal.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/loginmodal.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/loginmodal.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Modal button -->
    <button id="modBtn" class="modal-btn">Open Modal</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="header-title">Modal Header</h3>
            <div class="close fa fa-close"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Hello</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

loginmodal.js:

```
$(function () {
    // Vars
    var modBtn = $('#modBtn'),
        modal = $('#modal'),
        close = modal.find('.close'),
        modContent = modal.find('.modal-content');

    // open modal when click on open modal button 
    modBtn.on('click', function () {
        modal.css('display', 'block');
        modContent.removeClass('modal-animated-out').addClass('modal-animated-in');
    });

    // close modal when click on close button or somewhere out the modal content 
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (target.is(modal) || target.is(close)) {
            modContent.removeClass('modal-animated-in').addClass('modal-animated-out').delay(300).queue(function (next) {
                modal.css('display', 'none');
                next();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Somewhere in index.cshtml:

```
...
@Html.Partial("LoginModal")
...
```

The button is there but doesn't do anything, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: since your question is related to bootstrap as well, adding the bootstrap tag will be helpful

Comment: a partial class shouldn't be containing the `head` tag by the way. you can use sections in razor

Comment: have you tried `<button id="modBtn" class="modal-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>`?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane  This does make the modal popup but it 'freezes', so there's no way to close it without refreshing. The modal works fine on online editors.  Also I don't think bootstrap is being applied here

Comment: which online editors did you try it in? the code I gave you was bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp, you can use the following to open and close the modal.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Modal button -->
    <button id="modBtn" class="modal-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="header-title">Modal Header</h3>
            <div class="close fa fa-close"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Hello</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your css and js references which are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/loginmodal.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/loginmodal.js"></script>
```

And the button to open it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Modal button -->
    <button id="modBtn" class="modal-btn">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

should be placed inside `Index.cshtml` instead of the login partial view.

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Comment: I missed something in my original answer. Please see update.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Either way I know the references are working because the css is being applied whether it's in index or in the partial view

Comment: Can you verify that the `click` handler of `modBtn` is being called when you click on the button?

Comment: moving an HTML from the partial to the main view doesn't make a difference in terms of HTML code output. Moreover, the button code placement is up to the OP based on his plans for reusability